# strange rails assets css images behavior (and probably other stuff)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, asset-pipeline

I have a pretty vanilla rails app with all my images in app/assets/images, and my stylesheets in app/assets/stylesheets.
In my styles I have:

```
body
  background: url(/assets/bg.png)
  //background: image-path('bg.png')--well, same thing also doesn't work
```

This image does not appear, although if I have `=image_tag 'bg.png'` in the view, it works just fine (but does not have the generated timestamp at the end (not `bg.png?<buncha#s>`).

If I go to `localhost:3000/assets/bg.png`, it is there, as are all my images--except one called `diag_bg.png` in which case I get a `Errno::ENOTDIR Not a directory - project/app/assets/images/diag_bg` which is super weird.  Well whether the image is there or not, I cannot use it as a css background even if I can access it that way.  Also firebug shows there is no GET request for the css image at all.

-btw, none of these images are in public/images unless I manually rake precompile the assets (I never set the precompile to false in dev).  But it seems like those images aren't even getting used...(kinda confused about them)

Also I get these messages.  I'm not sure if it's normal (logo_small.png is the single =image_tag so far):

```
Started GET "/assets/main.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-22 14:31:33 -0700
Served asset /main.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2012-04-22 14:31:33] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true    

Started GET "/assets/logo_small.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-22 14:31:33 -0700
Served asset /logo_small.png - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2012-04-22 14:31:33] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

Any help would be appreciated...I'm pretty frustrated with assets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
background: image-url("bg.png")
```

The `image-url` helper is the one you want, you need to quote the path, and you do not need to put `/assets` in front. Only include a folder if your image is located in a subfolder, for instance:

```
app/assets/images/icons/favorite.png
```

...would be referenced as:

```
background: image-url("icons/favorite.png")
```

See https://github.com/rails/sass-rails for more information.

Comment: Oh doh.  I didn't read that clearly the first time...thanks :)

Comment: i'm still kind of confused on why the timestamp thing isn't generated anymore, and where the compiled sass/images/etc are...do you have any idea?

Comment: You should probably check the rails and sprockets changelogs, timestamp is a config setting so if you search for rails asset config options you'll probably find some explanations. Off the top of my head I don't know if or when that default changed. Compiled images live in your `public/assets` dir.